# Is it possible to put a network load balancer in front of a Gateway VPC endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

I have a weird use case where I need to create an [AWS VPC endpoint service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) that forwards requests to DynamoDB. Thus, I'm wondering is it possible to configure a network load balancer to send traffic to a [Gateway VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html)?

Comment: why you need ELB before API gateway?

Comment: @TuanVA Can you create an endpoint service using API gateway? I couldn't find anything in the AWS docs regarding this.

Comment: From internal, you can call API gateway via VPC endpoint. But I don't understand the reason why need ELB before API gateway

Comment: Please describe, more specifically, the problem you are trying to solve, rather than your attempted solution (NLB to Gateway endpoint is not possible).  *Why* do you need a VPC endpoint service that forwards requests to DynamoDB, and what does "forward" mean?  Typically a "forwarded" request is unmodified other than possibly some manipulation of request/response headers, so "forwarded" might not be the most optimum way to describe what you need.

Comment: I have the same question, but I have the following challenge: we have a VPC with an `ApiGateway::RestApi` with PRIVATE endpoints (they are only accessible from the VPC). So the idea is that NLB (accessible from anywhere in the world) will translate the traffic to the API. Is it possiable to implement in AWS?